# Adding a new class from XSLT to an existing class of div tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

```
<div class="filter">
 <xsl:attribute name="class">

                <xsl:if test="@class=filter">
                  filter
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="Category"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

i want to add a new class which  i get from the xsl value to the upper div containing **filter** **class**.but the way i am doing it just remove my **previous class** and **add new class**.But i want to add both classes at the same time.

Comment: and what's your input xml?

Comment: Can you show the output you expect? Are you expecting `<div class="filter anotherclass">` or `<div class="filter" class="anotherclass">`. In the second case, that is not allowed as you can't have duplicate attribute names.

Comment: please tell me the code for adding both class....from <xsl:value-of select="Category"/> i have generated new class

Comment: Yes i want exactly as the first case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `<xsl:if test="@class=filter">` is probably not doing what you expect it to do.

Firstly it is comparing the attribute `class` with an element named `filter` in your XML (which probably doesn't exist). It's possible you meant to compare the class with a string value, which you would do like so:

```
<xsl:if test="@class='filter'">
```

However, this leads on to the second problem. This test is checking for a class attribute in your input XML (which you have not shown), on what ever element you have currently matched. It is not checking the class attribute your have just created on the `<div>` in your output.

Using `xsl:attribute` will replace any existing attribute on the element you are processing, so you don't need to put `class="filter"` on the `<div>`. You can just do this....

```
<div>
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
     <xsl:text>filter </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="Category"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

Better still, use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates), which will allow you to add the `class` attribute to the `<div>` tag directly

```
<div class="filter {Category}" />
```

So, "filter" will be output as a string, but the curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, so the value of the `Category` element will be output here.